# Can I make this T-SQL code more efficient

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am running a SQL query on a table containing 3 million records comparing email addresses.

We have two email address fields, primary and secondary.

I am comparing a subset of primary emails against all other primary and secondary Emails to get a count of both duplicates and unique Emails in the data.

I believe this code works, its still running 10 mins in, and I have to do this for another 9 subsets which are alot larger than this one. Code is as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS UniqueRecords
FROM AllVRContacts 
WHERE LEN(EMAIL) > 1 AND ACCOUNTID = '00120000003bNmMAAU'

AND EMAIL NOT IN
(SELECT EMAIL FROM AllVRContacts WHERE ACCOUNTID != '00120000003bNmMAAU')

AND EMAIL NOT IN
(SELECT SECONDARY_EMAIL_ADDRESS__C FROM AllVRContacts WHERE ACCOUNTID != '00120000003bNmMAAU')
```

I want to learn something from this rather than just have someone scratch my back for me, the more explanation the better!

Thanks guys,

Comment: How many records are there with `ACCOUNTID = '00120000003bNmMAAU'`?

Comment: My first guess you can use filter like this SELECT COUNT(*) AS UniqueRecords
FROM AllVRContacts 
WHERE ACCOUNTID = '00120000003bNmMAAU' AND LEN(EMAIL) > 1

Comment: I see that you're comparing e-mails, but what are you looking for? Your current query looks like you want a count of e-mails the account has that is unique to the account (i.e. each e-mail included in the account is not associated with any other account as a primary or secondary e-mail). Is that what you're looking for? BTW, your current query will give you an overcount should an account duplicate its e-mail...

Comment: Can there be duplicates on `Email` within the same `AccountID`?

Comment: There can indeed, although we are not interested in them, I suppose this has an impact on our results?

Comment: @Yoda: on this the results depends. If you have two same emails within given account which have no matches in other accounts, do you want to be `1` or `2` returned as a result?

Comment: in this instance we would only want a 1 returned as we are only interested in those which are duplicated across accounts rather than within accounts

Comment: I know you've already selected your answer, but as I said in my comment earlier, your query will overcount should an account duplicate its e-mail. My response below should be useful in addressing this issue - good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the following indexes:

```
AllVrContacts (AccountID) INCLUDE (Email)
AllVrContacts (Email) INCLUDE (AccountID)
AllVrContacts (SECONDARY_EMAIL_ADDRESS__C) INCLUDE (AccountID)
```

The index on `(AccountID, Email)` will be used for the `WHERE` filter in the main query:

```
WHERE  ACCOUNTID = '00120000003bNmMAAU'
       AND LEN(Email) > 1
```

The other two indexes will be used for antijoins (`NOT IN`) against this table.

You should also use:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT email) AS UniqueRecords
```

if you want the duplicates across the same account to be counted only once.

Comment: On the first Index you suggest I am getting an error saying: Cannot create a primary key or index exceeding 900 bytes

Comment: @Yoda: how long (at most) are your `accountId`?

Comment: I think I know why this has happened, when I imported the data from a CSV file I made the field lengths 5000 to avoid import errors, I will rectify this now. That should fix it.

Comment: Whilst talking about it, that seems like a ridiculous way to do it, it is how my boss showed me and im sure its unneccesary

Comment: @Yoda: you can also make `Email` in the first index a non-key column, this will make it less in size.

Comment: Thanks for your help, deffinately earned that green tick! Much appriciated

Comment: Congrats, Quassnoi, although I thought the question was how to improve the T-SQL, not just the performance =)

Comment: @bitxwise: strictly speaking, the question was "how to make this code more efficient". I shouldn't have touched the code at all! :)

Comment: @Quassnoi: There's a difference between "efficient T-SQL" and "efficient query performance" - I was assuming he meant the former =)

Comment: @bitwise, no there is not a difference between "efficient T-SQL" and "efficient query performance". If you are writing t-sql to look efficient rather than be performant you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @HLGEM: wonder if the guy ever sees his messages, with a nick like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   (SELECT EMAIL AS UniqueRecords
        FROM   AllVRContacts a
        WHERE  ACCOUNTID = '00120000003bNmMAAU'
               AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT EMAIL FROM AllVRContacts b
                               WHERE ACCOUNTID != '00120000003bNmMAAU'
                                     AND (
                                          a.EMAIL = b.EMAIL
                                          OR a.EMAIL = b.SECONDARY_EMAIL_ADDRESS__C
                                     )
               )
               AND LEN(EMAIL) > 1
        GROUP  BY EMAIL
) c
```

So how is this query better?

1. You typically want to use NOT EXISTS instead of NOT IN

   `IN` returns true if a specified value matches any value in a subquery or a list

   `EXISTS` returns true if a subquery contains any rows

   More Info: [SQL Server: JOIN vs IN vs EXISTS - the logical difference](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/05/18/60210.aspx)
2. = performs much better than !=
3. Reduce the scans (seeks if you have indexes on AllVRContacts) by not searching through AllVRContacts a second time for the secondary e-mail comparison
4. `GROUP BY` resolves potential duplicate e-mails within the ACCOUNTID

To further improve performance, add indexes as Quassnoi suggested and whatever is populating the table should validate e-mails to remove the need for the LEN check.

[EDIT] Added explanation to (3)

Comment: in an equality correlation, `NOT EXITST` and `NOT IN` are optimized to the same plan. http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/

Comment: @Quassnoi: That may be (I've yet to fully verify the validity) but I was referencing the LOGICAL difference, not the performance difference =)

Answer (score 1):

Can this be applicable?

```
SELECT ACCOUNTID, COUNT(*) AS UniqueRecords
FROM (
  SELECT ACCOUNTID, EMAIL
  FROM AllVRContacts
  WHERE ACCOUNTID = '00120000003bNmMAAU' AND LEN(EMAIL) > 1
  UNION
  SELECT ACCOUNTID, SECONDARY_EMAIL_ADDRESS__C
  FROM AllVRContacts
  WHERE ACCOUNTID = '00120000003bNmMAAU' AND LEN(SECONDARY_EMAIL_ADDRESS__C) > 1
) s
```

I understood that basically you wanted to count distinct email addresses for each ACCOUNTID.

UNION in the inner query eliminates duplicates so the output (of the inner query) only has distinct pairs of account ids and emails, whether primary or secondary. Particularly this means that if an email address is stored as both primary and secondary, it will count only once. Same applies to same primary or same secondary address stored in different rows.

Now you only need to count the rows, which is done by the outer query.

If another 9 subsets you've mentioned mean simply other ACCOUNTIDs, then maybe you could try `GROUP BY ACCOUNTID` applied to the outer query and the `ACCOUNTID = '...'` part of both `WHERE` clauses got rid of to count emails for all of them with one query. That is, like this:

```
SELECT ACCOUNTID, COUNT(*) AS UniqueRecords
FROM (
  SELECT ACCOUNTID, EMAIL
  FROM AllVRContacts
  WHERE LEN(EMAIL) > 1
  UNION
  SELECT ACCOUNTID, SECONDARY_EMAIL_ADDRESS__C
  FROM AllVRContacts
  WHERE LEN(SECONDARY_EMAIL_ADDRESS__C) > 1
) s
GROUP BY ACCOUNTID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know

SELECT ACCOUNTID,COUNT(*) AS UniqueRecords 
FROM AllVRContacts
WHERE LEN(EMAIL) > 1 AND ACCOUNTID = '00120000003bNmMAAU'
Group by ACCOUNTID
Having COUNT(EMAIL) >1

Comment: This will return records which are duplicated within the account ID specified, which is not the intent of the code.